# Run multiple Jenkins jobs on single node(single machine)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-jira-trigger

I have a parametrised jenkins job which I trigger via a script. The job creates a VM instance and does its job on the VM. Now the number of actual machines I have is limited (I have 3 actual machines). So I want to run multiple jenkins jobs on a single machine (node) so that I can spawn multiple VMs on a machine and do multiple jobs(6 jobs in parallel).

I searched a lot of options for this but did not find any good solutions. Is this possible? If yes how?

Comment: Yes this is possible, It depends how many executors you have configured for the node.

Comment: @HimanshuGupta Any links or examples I can look at?

Comment: Refer to this https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/